Could there be any negative repercussions in disabling com.apple.ftp-proxy.plist?
I noticed there was something listening on port 8021 on my Mac.
$ sudo lsof -i ':8021'
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
launchd   1 root   38u  IPv6 0xe1f07e87cd655321      0t0  TCP localhost:intu-ec-client (LISTEN)
launchd   1 root   39u  IPv4 0xe1f07e87bd752671      0t0  TCP localhost:intu-ec-client (LISTEN)
launchd   1 root   46u  IPv6 0xe1f07e87cd655321      0t0  TCP localhost:intu-ec-client (LISTEN)
launchd   1 root   51u  IPv4 0xe1f07e87bd752671      0t0  TCP localhost:intu-ec-client (LISTEN)

What is `intu-ec-client` listening on TCP port 8021? pointed me at the file
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.ftp-proxy.plist
Sure enough, the file contained
<key>Listeners</key>
<dict>
    <key>SockNodeName</key>
    <string>localhost</string>
    <key>SockServiceName</key>
    <string>8021</string>
    <key>SockType</key>
    <string>stream</string>
</dict>

I was able to stop this daemon with
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.ftp-proxy.plist

Does anyone know what the purpose of this service is and whether stopping it could cause any problems?

If that is indeed the post you are referring to, then you should have included the link.

It does not answer my question.

I don't have this service running on Sonoma.

Me neither, but then it might be an on-demand type of listener. I would imagine macOS has them, I'm more familiar with the Linux on-demand ones... If so, then the OP might have something else running as the traffic endpoint. intu-ec-client is just some 'well known' usage of that port from the past, referenced in /etc/services
